# Are there any order analysis functions in Python?

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, python

I would like to perform the following order related tasks in Python:

1. Convert tachometer pulse signal to RPM signal ([tachorpm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tachorpm.html))
2. Convert RPM signal to even-angle signal ([orderwaveform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/orderwaveform.html))
3. Time synchronous averaging ([tsa](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tsa.html))

I am aware of that MATLAB has these functions but I did not find any in Python. Does anyone know?

Comment: none of these things sound like something a matlab function can do on its own, so I'm a bit confused what you actually have! Also, we don't know what your input signal looks like? is it timestamps of pulses? A sequence of durations between pulses? the (binary) pulse input sampled at regular intervals? Or something else?

Comment: I updated matched functions in MATLAB with help links

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can find an implementation to those functions (you might do if you will look long enough). Main point, each of those functions might be implemented in several lines so there is no point for you to look for them. For example, TSA is a simple resampling with avarageing, right? You can validate the process by opening the code of each of those functions.